# Does the Tireless spell increase your normal movement rate?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, magic

The Tireless spell (*Deep Magic*, Kobold Press) says:

> You grant machinelike stamina to a creature you touch for the duration of the spell. The target requires no food or drink or rest. It can move at three times its normal speed overland and perform three times the usual amount of labor. The target is not protected from fatigue or exhaustion caused by a magical effect.

Does this affect the target's normal movement rate (such as tripling a 30' movement to 90')?

Comment: Reminder to everyone that answers, even partial answers or suggestions on how to get an answer, belong in answer posts, not in comments.

Answer (score 10):

### The Tireless spell affects long distance movement

"*Overland*" is an older term from [3.5e](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/movement.htm) and [Pathfinder](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/exploration-movement/#TOC-Overland-Movement) which referred to long distance, non-combat movement rates:

> There are three movement scales, as follows.
>
> - Tactical, for combat, measured in feet (or squares) per round.
> - Local, for exploring an area, measured in feet per minute.
> - Overland, for getting from place to place, measured in miles per hour or miles per day.

The [5e movement rules](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Movement#content) instead now use the term "*Travel Pace*" to refer to non-combat, long distance movement rates (Kobold Press likely just used the older term by accident, as they've accidently used older terms elsewhere in their 5e publications).

> **Travel Pace:** While traveling, a group of adventurers can move at a normal, fast, or slow pace, as shown on the Travel Pace table. The table states how far the party can move in a period of time...

Example from 5e: the Elk [totem barbarian's](http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/barbarian:totem-warrior) Aspect of the Beast feature says "*...your travel pace is doubled, as is the travel pace of up to ten companions ...*". This refers to non-combat, long distance movement rates.